# Cant create text with EZDXF

Tags: python-3.x, ezdxf

Im trying to create text with ezdxf but when i open the file it doesnt show anything!
With lines etc it works. I tried with the example in the documentation but that also doesnt work!

```
import ezdxf

# TEXT is a basic entity and is supported by every DXF version.
# Argument setup=True for adding standard linetypes and text styles.
doc = ezdxf.new('R12', setup=True)
msp = doc.modelspace()

# use set_pos() for proper TEXT alignment:
# The relations between DXF attributes 'halign', 'valign',
# 'insert' and 'align_point' are tricky.
msp.add_text("A Simple Text").set_pos((2, 3), align='MIDDLE_RIGHT')

# Using a text style
msp.add_text("Text Style Example: Liberation Serif",
             dxfattribs={
                 'style': 'LiberationSerif',
                 'height': 0.35}
             ).set_pos((2, 6), align='LEFT')

doc.saveas("simple_text.dxf")
```

Answer (score 0):

`set_pos` seems to be deprecated since version 0.18, it's `set_placement` now.

Check https://github.com/mozman/ezdxf/blob/master/examples/using_all_text_styles.py